# Magento 2 : State dropdown showing regionID is required field

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2.1. On Admin side on order creation page, some specific countries have states in dropdown. I need to show state dropdown for India country. For this purpose I have fired following 2 queries.

```
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` VALUES
(548 , 'IN', '35','Andaman Nicobar'),
(549 , 'IN', '28','Andhra Pradesh'),
(550 , 'IN', '12','Arunachal Pradesh'),
(551 , 'IN', '18','Assam'),
(552 , 'IN', '10','Bihar'),
(553 , 'IN', '04','Chandigarh'),
(554 , 'IN', '22','Chhattisgarh'),
(555 , 'IN', '26','Dadra Nagar Haveli'),
(556 , 'IN', '25','Daman Diu'),
(557 , 'IN', '07','Delhi'),
(558 , 'IN', '30','Goa'),
(559 , 'IN', '24','Gujarat'),
(560 , 'IN', '06','Haryana'),
(561 , 'IN', '02','Himachal Pradesh'),
(562 , 'IN', '01','Jammu Kashmir'),
(563 , 'IN', '20','Jharkhand'),
(564 , 'IN', '29','Karnataka'),
(565 , 'IN', '32','Kerala'),
(566 , 'IN', '31','Lakshadweep'),
(567 , 'IN', '23','Madhya Pradesh'),
(568 , 'IN', '27','Maharashtra'),
(569 , 'IN', '14','Manipur'),
(570 , 'IN', '17','Meghalaya'),
(571 , 'IN', '15','Mizoram'),
(572 , 'IN', '13','Nagaland'),
(573 , 'IN', '21','Odisha'),
(574 , 'IN', '34','Pondicherry'),
(575 , 'IN', '03','Punjab'),
(576 , 'IN', '08','Rajasthan'),
(577 , 'IN', '11','Sikkim'),
(578 , 'IN', '33','Tamil Nadu'),
(579 , 'IN', '36','Telangana'),
(580 , 'IN', '16','Tripura'),
(581 , 'IN', '09','Uttar Pradesh'),
(582 , 'IN', '05','Uttaranchal'),
(583 , 'IN', '19','West Bengal');
```

Second Query :

```
INSERT INTO `directory_country_region_name` (`locale`, `region_id`, `name`) VALUES
('en_US',548,'Andaman Nicobar'),
('en_US',549,'Andra Pradesh'),
('en_US',550,'Arunachal Pradesh'),
('en_US',551,'Assam'),
('en_US',552,'Bihar'),
('en_US',553,'Chandigarh'),
('en_US',554,'Chhattisgarh'),
('en_US',555,'Dadar and Nagar Haveli'),
('en_US',556,'Daman Diu'),
('en_US',557,'Delhi'),
('en_US',558,'Goa'),
('en_US',559,'Gujarat'),
('en_US',560,'Haryana'),
('en_US',561,'Himachal Pradesh'),
('en_US',562,'Jammu and Kashmir'),
('en_US',563,'Jharkhand'),
('en_US',564,'Karnataka'),
('en_US',565,'Kerala'),
('en_US',566,'Lakshadweep'),
('en_US',567,'Madhya Pradesh'),
('en_US',568,'Maharashtra'),
('en_US',569,'Manipur'),
('en_US',570,'Meghalaya'),
('en_US',571,'Mizoram'),
('en_US',572,'Nagaland'),
('en_US',573,'Odisha'),
('en_US',574,'Pondicherry'),
('en_US',575,'Punjab'),
('en_US',576,'Rajasthan'),
('en_US',577,'Sikkim'),
('en_US',578,'Tamil Nadu'),
('en_US',579,'Telangana'),
('en_US',580,'Tripura'),
('en_US',581,'Uttar Pradesh'),
('en_US',582,'Uttaranchal'),
('en_US',583,'West Bengal');
```

After firing above queries, on order page, in country dropdown when I select India, state dropdown is getting populated. But when I select state and fills other required info and submits page, it is showing me following error.

> "regionId is a required field."

Not able to fix this issue. Kindly help if anyone knows.

Comment: No one has idea about this? :(

Comment: I have added state for India, it's working good and also create order from admin successfully without any error. I have try Country 'India' with state. You can one more try after reindexing and clean cache. I hope it will work for you. Great Question.

Comment: I have done reindexing and cleared cache as well. But still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated `general/region/state_required` config value in `core_config_data` list with `AT,BR,CA,CH,EE,ES,FI,HR,IN,LT,LV,RO,US`
Updating this should work for you else you can simply rollback your query and install this module to solve your problem.

This module updates all required database entries and show drop-down for states in frontend.

https://packagist.org/packages/credevlabz/magento2-directory-indian-states